# get number of rows select statement will fetch (without real fetching)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have many sql statements like this one:

```
  select * 
    from [A] 
   where a in (
         select a 
           from [B] 
          where b = 'c'
         ) 
order by d;
```

Since my database is huge, I just need to determine how many rows this query will fetch. Of course I can really fetch all rows and count it but my intention is to avoid fetching since that would be a big overhead.

I have tried to extend query as follows:

```
  select count (*) 
    from (
           select * 
             from [A] 
            where a in (
                  select a 
                    from [B] 
                   where b = 'c'
                  ) 
         order by d
         ) as table;
```

That works fine for some tables but for some (like this one in example) SQL server throws this:

*The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.*

Consider that I'm not allowed to change any original query, I can just extend it...

Any idea?
Thanks.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure there is some solution related to @@ROWCOUNT field, but not sure how to use it...

Comment: The real problem is the requirement. Fetch and count as you fetch. counting before fetching is a waste of resources, the server has to do the work twice. for no reason.

Comment: It isn't possible to convert a query like `SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY C` to a count query just by adding surrounding syntax. One thing you can do is view the estimated execution plan for it and see the estimated number of rows. May well not be accurate though.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `order by` in the subquery.  It doesn't affect the number of rows:

```
select count(*)
from (select *
      from [A]
      where a in (select a from [B] where b = 'c') 
     ) as table;
```

Actually, this is better written as:

```
select count(*)
from [A]
where a in (select a from [B] where b = 'c')
```

That is, just replace the `select *` with `select count(*)`.

Finally, if you have to keep the queries the same, then use `top 100 percent`:

```
select count(*)
from (select top 100 percent *
      from [A]
      where a in (select a from [B] where b = 'c') 
      order by d
     ) as table;
```

This *does* require changing the original queries, but in a way that does not affect what they output and does allow them to be used as ctes/subqueries.

You are allowed to use `order by` in subqueries when you also use `top`.

EDIT:

If you are using dynamic SQL, you might have to do something like:

```
@sql = 'select count(*) from (' +
       (case when @sql not like 'SELECT TOP %'
             then stuff(@sql, 1, 7, 'SELECT top 100 percent')
             else @sql
        end) +
        + ')';
```

The logic could be a bit more complicated if your SQL is not well formatted.

Comment: "I'm not allowed to change any original query, I can just extend it"

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . The answer now addresses that.  I am a little vague on exactly what "extending" a query means.

Comment: Thank you all, but Martin is right. Original query must remains the same.